# Sending a high and low price limit through a link

Tags: php

Can anyone help me with this line of code?

```
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?price<=$high&price>=$low&currentpage=1'><<</a>

$high
```

and

```
$low
```

are price limits for searching products by price
When I click on a page link, I need to send $high and $low to that page to compare the 'price' field in my db and show all records between the prices.

My line of code just returns nothing.

Comment: What line of code returns nothing?

Comment: You can't check value is greater than or less than in a url? use assignment operator only. 

ex : `price='.$high.' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `<=` or `>=` in params, just use different words for every price

```
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?highPrice={$high}&lowPrice={$low}&currentpage=1'><<</a>
```

Then in PHP  you can recover these values:

```
<?php
    $high = $_GET['highPrice'];
    $low = $_GET['lowPrice'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?high='.$high.'&low='.$low.'&currentpage=1"><<</a>';
?>
```

To retrieve the values from the GET-request, do this:

```
<?php
$high = $_GET['high'];
$low = $_GET['low'];
?>
```

Also, be sure to sanitize your GET-data.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply Try This

```
<a href='Link?high=$high&low=$low&currentpage=1'> Test </a>
```

In Php Script

```
$high = $_GET["high"]; $low = $_GET["low"];
$query = mysql_query("select * from table where price <= $high and price >= $low ");
```